# Sharing my application without exposing my classes

Tags: java, jar, shared-libraries

How do I package my application to be used in other projects without exposing my classes or code with one entry point for the other developer to use?

I don't want to use any dependencies and if there is a way of bundling the classes or total project to be executable with one entry point with the best cybersafety practices.

Comment: Usually you ship Java code in jar files, or make them available in repositories like https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central You will have to expose the classes that the users of your code need, of course. You can make other classes (package-) private, and you can look into [the Java module system](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html). There are some code obfuscators for Java, which make it harder to disassemble the jar file and get the source code, if you are concerned about others stealing your code.